# ESP32 Debugging in VS Code - Cannot find compatible tool-openocd-esp32 for linux_i686

Tags: esp32, openocd, platformio

Environment:
Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS, 
VS Code 1.35.1, 
PlatformIO IDE 1.10.0, 
Arduino libraries for ESP32.

When attempting to open the debug interface in VS code, I am presented with the following error.

*PackageManager: Installing tool-openocd-esp32 @ ~1.1000.20181026
Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement '~1.1000.20181026' for your system 'linux_i686'*

The last time I debugged this project (or anything in VS code) was a year ago and I am fairly certain it worked then.

Sorry if this is a basic question but two hours of futile research has left me with no other option.

Comment: Does it give this line: `Please try this solution -> http:// bit.ly / faq-package-manager`? And did you try these?

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. I did not receive this suggestion in VSCode, but following the link now, it gave me a number of tricks to try. Unfortunately none of them worked. Deleting the packages folder did trigger a re-download of the packages, but only the ones needed for running the code normally - not this one, which only seems needed for debug. The manual download (of the version it required and a more up-to-date one) also strangely did not work being placed in the packages folder. Again, thank you for your suggestion